# Model and Stores concept in Android programming (like Sencha Touch)

Tags: android, android-listview, sencha-touch, android-sqlite, android-adapter

I am coming from a Sencha Touch background into Android/ Java programming.

For a simple List based application (say a Note, that has a Note Title, Note Text, Note Author, Note Date Created, Note Comments),you could define a `Note model` with Title, Text, Author, Date Created and a `Comments` model, that has the Comments Text and Linked Note object/instance. (the basic way to make a database design)

You can then define a Data Store (a local database) that knows which endpoint to fetch the serialized Notes data from (essential a JSON array of Note objects, with embedded comments objects inside them), and define functions to draw out useful info out of the JSON array and put it into the Notes object

The View (the actual list display of notes) then accesses the Notes Stores and anytime the Store is changed the ListView is updated automatically.

Is there such an elegant mechanism in Android? I experimented with ORMLite (which is somewhat similar to stores), but is there a way to achieve this tight external endpoint -- local store -- list view binding in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Android offers but one type of database, SQLite. While there are other storage options (file system, preferences, etc) it sounds like you def want a DB. Android has a nice write up for all [storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), and here's the [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) section.

To bind that data with a ListView, you'll need to use a [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html). If you don't want to handle the view generation part, you can instead use the [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html). However they are more or less the same thing. As the name implies, these adapters work with Cursors. [Cursors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html) just expose the results of running a query on a database.

To achieve the automatic updates, you'll need to use a [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html). Basically this guy handles querying for data on a background thread, then feed you the results on the UI thread. When there is a relevant change in the DB, it'll re-run the query and return you the latest data.  Android has a nice [write up](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html) explaining how to do this.

Comment: thanks Jay Soyer. My full aim is 1) GET data from an external api endpoint via Retrofit (and using GSON, OkHttp with it) 2) Once the data is fetched it is usually stored in memory in a subclass of BaseAdapter 3)I refresh teh ListView to which the BaseAdapter subclass is linked. Additionally, I might store the data in (2) inside a database for persistence across sessions. However, I was thinking why not store the data in a Database linked adapter in the first place. Is this achievable by CursorAdapter?

Comment: Yup. That's exactly the point of them. To link your ListView with a DB.